# setting macvlan bridge for lxc containers

Tags: lxc

I am trying to create containers which can be accessed from outside. So i've chosen the macvlan mode of networking which can assign an IP to the containers in the same network as the host.
I have added the following in my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto macvlan0

iface macvlan0 inet static

pre-up route del default

pre-up route del -net aa.bb.cc.0 netmask 255.255.255.0

pre-up ip link add link eth0 name macvlan0 type macvlan mode bridge

address 192.168.171.141
this creates a macvlan bridge by the name macvlan0 but i am not able to ping it from inside the container

this is the conf file of my container (i've mentioned only the nerworking part)

 lxc.network.type = macvlan

 lxc.network.macvlan.mode = bridge

 lxc.network.flags = up

 lxc.network.link = eth0

 lxc.network.ipv4 = aa.bb.cc.155/24
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?